# How can we Draw a lines between 2 panels in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jtable

Just want to connect panels by drawing a line b/w them.

I am having two panels and both panels contains a Jtable.I want to connect each cell of jtable of one panel to another Jtable of another jpanel.

[image]

Here i want to draw the lines like that i have highlighted by pink color circle.

and this is the code snippet i am using to create jtables

```
 DefaultTableModel fcdbDataModel = new DefaultTableModel(fcdbIdTxnArray,
    fcdbIdTxnColumnArray);
fcdbIdTxnJTable = new FieldMapperJTable(fcdbDataModel);
```

here FieldMapperJTable is my customized jtable class.

Comment: Any type of help or idea of using another way would be appreciated.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Stanislav Thank you so much for your post.This was worked for me. "http://java-sl.com/connector.html"

Comment: @Will wondering why you deleted Stani's answer - it's definitely helpful

Comment: @kleopatra that post was really nice and knowledge gaining.

Comment: repeating the link (your copy contains the last quotation mark, so gives on 404) [JConnector project](http://java-sl.com/connector.html) by @Stanislav

Answer (score 8):

You could easily do that using JFrame/JDialog GlassPane as the painting field. Just set your custom component as a glass pane for the frame and paint the link directly on it.

You can also do the same using the layered pane of the frame/dialog.

Here is a small working example of how to draw such "links" on the glass pane component:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389479/909085
 */

public class ComponentLinkerTest extends JComponent
{
    private Map<JComponent, JComponent> linked;

    public ComponentLinkerTest ()
    {
        super ();
        linked = new HashMap<JComponent, JComponent> ();
    }

    public void link ( JComponent c1, JComponent c2 )
    {
        linked.put ( c1, c2 );
        repaint ();
    }

    protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        g2d.setPaint ( Color.BLACK );
        for ( JComponent c1 : linked.keySet () )
        {
            Point p1 = getRectCenter ( getBoundsInWindow ( c1 ) );
            Point p2 = getRectCenter ( getBoundsInWindow ( linked.get ( c1 ) ) );
            g2d.drawLine ( p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y );
        }
    }

    private Point getRectCenter ( Rectangle rect )
    {
        return new Point ( rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2 );
    }

    private Rectangle getBoundsInWindow ( Component component )
    {
        return getRelativeBounds ( component, getRootPaneAncestor ( component ) );
    }

    private Rectangle getRelativeBounds ( Component component, Component relativeTo )
    {
        return new Rectangle ( getRelativeLocation ( component, relativeTo ),
                component.getSize () );
    }

    private Point getRelativeLocation ( Component component, Component relativeTo )
    {
        Point los = component.getLocationOnScreen ();
        Point rt = relativeTo.getLocationOnScreen ();
        return new Point ( los.x - rt.x, los.y - rt.y );
    }

    private JRootPane getRootPaneAncestor ( Component c )
    {
        for ( Container p = c.getParent (); p != null; p = p.getParent () )
        {
            if ( p instanceof JRootPane )
            {
                return ( JRootPane ) p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean contains ( int x, int y )
    {
        return false;
    }

    private static ComponentLinkerTest linker;

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        setupLookAndFeel ();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();

        linker = new ComponentLinkerTest ();
        frame.setGlassPane ( linker );
        linker.setVisible ( true );

        JPanel content = new JPanel ();
        content.setLayout ( new GridLayout ( 10, 5, 5, 5 ) );
        content.setBorder ( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder ( 5, 5, 5, 5 ) );
        frame.add ( content );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
        {
            final JButton button = new JButton ( "Button" + i );
            button.addActionListener ( new ActionListener ()
            {
                public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e )
                {
                    link ( button );
                }
            } );
            content.add ( button );
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private static JButton last = null;

    private static void link ( JButton button )
    {
        if ( last == null )
        {
            last = button;
        }
        else
        {
            linker.link ( last, button );
            last = null;
        }
    }

    private static void setupLookAndFeel ()
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName () );
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( InstantiationException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( IllegalAccessException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        catch ( UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:
(just click any two buttons one after another and they will get linked)
[image]

P.S. To make the lines thicker you can change the stroke when painting:

```
g2d.setStroke ( new BasicStroke ( 5f ) );
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this still applies but back in the days when Swing was new and shiny I ran in lots of problems handling events when trying to use the glasspane.

Comment: +1 For rendering atop the components, as well as an admirable comment style. :-)

Comment: @JensSchauder yes, there are problems, if you want the glasspane to handle any events at all (not problems, but small difficulties actually). Anyways, that is why i override "contains" method of the glass pane component. If you always return false there (or limit it with shape of the lines) - it won't "absorb" events anywhere (or just in the shape bounds, which is fine aswell).

Comment: @trashgod thanks, always trying to improve the code and comments as much as i can :)

Comment: repeating my comment to the deleted answer: @Sunil if you are on jdk7 you might consider to grab Stan's logic and implement it in a JLayer/UI. And similar for this: the bad ol' GlassPane is difficult to handle correctly (no change over the years).

Comment: @kleopatra JLayer might indeed be better (not sure how it works inside), but its still JDK7+ only. And i don't really see any problems using either glasspane or layeredpane - you just need to know some specific things that might affect overlayed components behavior.

Comment: true, for earlier versions I use [JXLayer](http://jxlayer.java.net) which is very similar and already very stable. As to _no problems with glasspane_ - I vividly remember Alexander struggling big style until the glasspane of the J/X/Layer was really safe and useful ;-) Forgot the details, though, you might want to search his blog at java.net if you are interested

Comment: @kleopatra yeh, well, i actually want to explore the JLayer that is now provided in JDK7 to see how exactly it works and what could be done with it. And what cannot be... as always :)

Comment: @kleopatra No sir, i m using jdk6.