# how can i check line between two buttons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent, jradiobutton

How can I check a line which is drawn with the help of drawline function between two radio button any function which help me for checking line is exist between these buttons or not?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12389479/909085
 */
public class ComponentLinkerTest extends JComponent {
    // private Map<JComponent, JComponent> linked;
    Map<JComponent, java.util.List<JComponent>> linked;// = new HashMap<>();
    int n = 1;

    public ComponentLinkerTest() {
        super();
        linked = new HashMap();
    }
    static JRadioButton[] button = new JRadioButton[25];

    public void gui() {
        setupLookAndFeel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        linker = new ComponentLinkerTest();
        frame.setGlassPane(linker);
        linker.setVisible(true);
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 5, 5));
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        frame.add(content);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            // final JButton button = new JButton ( "Button" + i );
            button[i] = new JRadioButton();
            //  panel.add(fontButtons[i]);
            button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    link((JRadioButton) e.getSource());
                }
            });
            content.add(button[i]);
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /*public void link ( JComponent c1, JComponent c2 )
     {
     linked.put ( c1, c2 );
     repaint ();
     }*/
    public void link(JComponent c1, JComponent c2) {
        if (linked.containsKey(c1)) {
            linked.get(c1).add(c2);
        } else {
            java.util.List<JComponent> list = new LinkedList<>();
            list.add(c2);
            linked.put(c1, list);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    /*  protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
     {
     Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
     g2d.setRenderingHint ( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
     g2d.setPaint ( Color.BLACK );
     for ( JComponent c1 : linked.keySet () )
     {
     Point p1 = getRectCenter ( getBoundsInWindow ( c1 ) );
     Point p2 = getRectCenter ( getBoundsInWindow ( linked.get ( c1 ) ) );
     /* Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(8//,
     /*BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0,
     new float[] { 12, 12 }, 0);
     g2d.setStroke(stroke);
     g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
     g2d.drawLine ( p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y );
     }
     }*/
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        for (JComponent c1 : linked.keySet()) {
            for (JComponent c2 : linked.get(c1)) {
                Point p1 = getRectCenter(getBoundsInWindow(c1));
                Point p2 = getRectCenter(getBoundsInWindow(c2));
                /* Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(8//,
                 /*BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0,
                 new float[] { 12, 12 }, 0);
                 g2d.setStroke(stroke);*/
                if (n == 1) {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    n = 2;
                } else {
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    n = 1;
                }
                g2d.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            }
        }
    }

    private Point getRectCenter(Rectangle rect) {
        return new Point(rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);
    }

    private Rectangle getBoundsInWindow(Component component) {
        return getRelativeBounds(component, getRootPaneAncestor(component));
    }

    private Rectangle getRelativeBounds(Component component, Component relativeTo) {
        return new Rectangle(getRelativeLocation(component, relativeTo),
                component.getSize());
    }

    private Point getRelativeLocation(Component component, Component relativeTo) {
        Point los = component.getLocationOnScreen();
        Point rt = relativeTo.getLocationOnScreen();
        return new Point(los.x - rt.x, los.y - rt.y);
    }

    private JRootPane getRootPaneAncestor(Component c) {
        for (Container p = c.getParent(); p != null; p = p.getParent()) {
            if (p instanceof JRootPane) {
                return (JRootPane) p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return false;
    }
    private static ComponentLinkerTest linker;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComponentLinkerTest ct = new ComponentLinkerTest();
        ct.gui();
    }
    private static JRadioButton last = null;

    private static void link(JRadioButton buton) {
        int a = 0;
        int i;
        if (last == null) {
            last = buton;
            System.out.println(last.getX());
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                if (buton == button[i]) {
                    /*if(button[i-1] == last || button[i+1]==last 
                     * || button[i-5] == last || button[i+5]==last)*/
                    if ((i > 0 && button[i - 1] == last)
                            || (i < (button.length - 1) && button[i + 1] == last)
                            || (i > 5 && button[i - 5] == last)
                            || (i < (button.length - 1) && button[i - 5] == last)) {
                        System.out.println("in cond");
                        linker.link(last, buton);
                        buton.setSelected(false);
                        last.setSelected(false);
                        last = null;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("out cond");
                        buton.setSelected(false);
                        last.setSelected(false);
                        last = null;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong position clicked ");
                    }
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("button not found");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private static void setupLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yup its my code and i want to check is it a square of adjacent radio butons is completed r not ...?

Comment: actually i picked it and understand it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable in your ComponentLinkerTest class. For example, it can be "isLineDraw" which is boolean and intialize it to false. When you draw a line between radio buttons, you can set this variable to true. Otherwise, it is set to false. Then, you can write a function simply controls this variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use grid coordinates, like they shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7702697/261156), you can find out of the corner coordinates form a rectangle, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2303278/261156).